# PHP Warning: Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 - Ubuntu/Nextcloud

Tags: ubuntu, php

I am seeing the following error when viewing the logs on my Ubuntu 18.04 server:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

How can I begin troubleshooting this? I am running php 7.4 and can provide whatever information is needed. This is for a server running Nextcloud.